# validation field with formik

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik, yup

I am using a form with **react-bootstrap, formik** and **yup**.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/formik-reactbootstrap-validation-xdihwi

The problem is that when I fill in the first field, the second is automatically in error whereas I would like the fields to be in error only when they are not filled in and only field by field.

if I fill in the 1st field then the second is in error.

[image]

Do you have a solution to correct this problem?

Comment: Most probably you are doing the validation of all fields on valiateOnChange and validateOnBlur. Check for these fields and what all fields you are validating each time. Is it all? Can you show us the code so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `handleBlur` and `touched` to solve this issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/formik-reactbootstrap-validation-tdkizk?file=src/App.js

```
<Form.Control
    value={formikProps.values.comment || ''}
    onChange={formikProps.handleChange}
    onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur}
    as="textarea"
    rows={3}
    name="comment"
    isInvalid={
      !!formikProps.touched.comment &&
      !!formikProps.errors.comment
    }
 />
```